# MySQL foreach?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two database tables, users and logs. I need SQL code to do something along the lines of

```
foreach(id in users)
  insert into logs a record with user_id = id;
endforeach;
```

I could use php to implement the foreach but I figured there is probably a pure SQL way of doing this. I'm running a MySQL server if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try a pattern similar to this

```
INSERT INTO logs (blah,blah)
SELECT foo,bar from Users
```

You should also read into something called Correlated subqueries if you need some type of logical connection between the two statements

Comment: Can blah,blah be column names from the users table ? i.e. can they be foo and bar

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO logs (user_id) SELECT id FROM users;
```

That will give you a blank `log` record for every user ID.